# struggling with simple CSS stuff

Tags: html, css

First off if someone can point me to a good reference that describes how css works and how to do basic stuff I would be very grateful!  I know the stuff is out there but finding it with search engines is problematic because of the way results are weighted towards things that describe individual elements from a height of one inch (2.5 cm ;) but I need something looking from a height of a couple of metres!

here is some simple html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">.indent: { margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 0 } </style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

```css
.indent { margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 0 }
```

```html
Some text ...
        <div class="indent">I want this indented:
          xxxxx
        </div>
```

```
  </body>
</html><br>
```

which renders as:

```
Some text ...
I want this indented: xxxx
```

I want the last line indented and I can do this by specifying the style in the div tag.  Further more I want to nest the divs and get another level of indenting.

Comment: remove the `:` after `.indent` in your css rule: `.indent { margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 0 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: too late :)
So, as @ray hatfield said by removeing the ":" behind ".indent"

**Tutorial**
For Tutorials try W3Schools with a lot of information to HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc.: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp

**CODE**
You can do it like this:

```css
.indent { margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 0 }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Some    text ...
    <div class="indent">I want this indented:
      xxxxx
    </div>
  </body>
</html><br>
```